# Mapping element of one array to another in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

Input Lines-

```
Rdd1 = (Array(6),Array(8))

Rdd2= Array((Array((2,2,5.0,1), (2,9,2.0,2))), (Array((1,1,5.0,1), (1,4,3.0,2), (1,2,2.5,3)))
```

I am want to map Rdd1 Array with each element of rdd2 Array-

```
Output- (Array((2,2,5.0,1,6), (2,9,2.0,2,6)),(Array((1,1,5.0,1,8), (1,4,3.0,2,8), (1,2,2.5,3,8)))
```

I am using Zip fucntion to join both Rdd. I tried using collect{case} pattern matching but, no success. Any idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: I'm picturing a reduce or flatmap-like operation

Comment: @cricket_007 I was using this "val p=e.zip(a).map(tuple => (tuple._1++tuple._2))" but, it is converting Array into Array[Any]. And, then I am not able to perform any operation on it

Comment: Do you have to keep the items as tuples? Can you not obtain them as collections?